# Is there any difference between literals and characters in c Programming?

Tags: c

I am learning C Programming
What is the difference between literal and character in C programming?

Comment: A "char literal" is a literal. A literal doesn't have to be a char. 'A', 2, 4U, 5.0f are all literals.

Comment: **literal**: some value appearing *textually* in a source file; **character** (really, I mean `char`) a definite set of values with specific characteristics

Comment: Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or a newer C standard. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal is a thing whose source code contains its value:

- `34` is source code for the `int` value 34.
- `'x'` is source code for the code for the character “x”.
- `"abc"` is source code for the sequence of characters “a”, “b”, and “c” (and a terminating null byte).

A character is a printed or displayed symbol. The word “character” is also used for a value of a `char` object or representable in the `char` type (or in the `signed char` or `unsigned char` types), although formally a `char` value like 65 only represents a character (like “a”) in the first sense (a printed or displayed symbol); 65 is not actually “a”.

In C, a character constant, like `'a'`, is a literal because it shows its value in the source text (it represent the number that is used as the code for the character “a”), but it is actually a constant of the type `int`, rather than `char`. So that is, somewhat confusingly, a character literal that does not have a character type. That unfortunate situation is due to the history of C development.

(Note: The definition of “literal” given here is a common meaning for it, not an official meaning of the C standard.)